# Is it appropriate to link in a tag wiki to tag-specific discussion forums?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I am quite active on the [huggingface-transformers] tag on Stack Overflow, and quite a lot of questions are relatively implementation-specific (and thus frequently remain unanswered due to their sheer length). However, I noticed that Huggingface themselves now have opened [their own discussion forum](https://discuss.huggingface.co/), which I think would be more suitable to some of the questions, or might even help others find answers they cannot find on SO.

**Now my question:**
Is it appropriate to include the link to the discussion forum in the tag description as an "outside resource" for further help?

While I could find some links in other tags (mainly directly pointing to the project), I couldn't find any example of linking to an external help site per se.

Comment: In the tag description? Sure, that's one of the uses for tag wikis, linking to other resources of information.

Comment: Yeah, sure, there are many links to helpful resources in SO's [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) tag wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to link to other resources in tag wikis.

> While I could find some links in other tags (mainly directly pointing to the project), I couldn't find any example of linking to an external help site per se.

An example: Stack Overflow's [regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) contains many links to external resources.